# Removing duplicate elements from a LinkedList in Java

Tags: java, while-loop, linked-list, duplicates

I've been working on an assignment that allows a user to enter Objects into a LinkedList, as well as remove them.  I have all areas of my program figured out except this pesky part here... removing duplicates.  I've been at this for some time now, and was hoping somebody could point me in the right direction.

The code I have below *almost* works... as in it does delete the duplicates... but only of the first element it encounters.  So, how do I allow the program to look at the first item, delete its duplicates, and then go back and do the same for all the other elements in the list?  Should I be using Nodes like "previous" and "current" rather than what I'm getting at here, and attempt to traverse the LinkedList that way? I was hinted by my professor that two while loops are needed, but all the ways I've tried it have not worked properly. What am I supposed to put as the parameter for the second, and I'm assuming, outer while loop?

Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!

```
public void removeDuplicate() //searches the LinkedList for duplicate elements, and removes them
   {
   ListIterator iter = listIterator();

   Object uniqueO = iter.next();

        while (iter.hasNext())
        {
           String uniqueS = (String) uniqueO;
           Object compareO = iter.next();
           String compareS = (String) compareO;
           int x = uniqueS.compareTo(compareS);
           if (x == 0)
           {
               iter.remove();
           }
        }

} //end removeDuplicate
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

it should be a set way .
But if you don't want to change the original  order , this can help:

//here, you can consider set as just a data structure which never tolerate duplicates :)

```
     public void removeDuplicate() //searches the LinkedList for duplicate elements, and removes them
   {
   ListIterator iter = listIterator();

    HashSet tempSet = new HashSet();


        while (iter.hasNext())
        {

        Object obj = iter.next();
                      if(tempSet.contains(obj))){
                          iter.remove();
                      }else{
                            tempSet.add(obj);
                      }
        }

} //end removeDuplicate
```

Comment: This definitely works well!  I think I will have to give in to using the Set, it is so much easier than what I was trying to do..  Thanks for the help =]

Answer (score 1):

If space is not a concern, you can always copy it to a new list, verifying before insertion that it is not yet in the new list:

```
public static LinkedList<Object> dedup(LinkedList<Object> original) {
    LinkedList<Object> copy = new LinkedList<Object>();

    for (Object o : original) {
        if (!copy.contains(o)) {
            copy.add(o);
        }
    }

    return copy;
}
```

You have stated that you already have an `add` function working, and you can implement a simple contains function fairly easily, for your `LinkedList` class:

```
public boolean contains(Object o) {
    ListIterator iter = listIterator();

    while (iter.hasNext()) {
        if (iter.next().equals(o)) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Comment: I like the idea of copying the list to a new list, because space is definitely not a concern.  Thanks for the input!

Answer (score 1):

```
private LinkedList<String> removeDups(LinkedList<String> linkedList){
    for(int i=0; i<linkedList.size(); i++){
        for(int j=i+1; j<linkedList.size(); j++){
            if(linkedList.get(i).equals(linkedList.get(j))){
                linkedList.remove(j);
            }
        }
    }
    return linkedList;
}
```

Comment: This is driving me insane. So If you change the int in the for loop to Integer, the code above does not work, it returns the linkedList exactly as it came in even if it has duplicate entries. Adding some debugging prints with Integer we do drop inside the if() with the correct indices for the original and duplicate item, but it seems the .remove doesn't work.

Comment: I have no idea, this answer was like years ago.

Comment: uggh it's because there's a remove(Object) and remove(int), If you're iterating with Integers you need to linkedList.remove((int) j) and then it works

Answer (score 0):

Convert it to a Set, then back to a List.
2 lines of code.

Comment: make sure to use a Set that maintains the original order.

Comment: We have not discussed Sets yet in my course, and although I have looked up Sets and seem to understand how it would work for this situation, it is not an option here unfortunately... =/

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this can help you , 
new a hashMap, and take the string value of link node as key, when iterating the list, check whether the key already exists in hashMap, if yes, just remove it.

Answer (score -1):

```
import java.util.HashSet;
```

import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class DeletDuplicateNodeinLinkList {

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    LinkedList<Integer> myLL = new LinkedList<Integer>();

    myLL.add(1231);
    myLL.add(12);
    myLL.add(12313);
    myLL.add(123);
    myLL.add(12313);
    myLL.add(1);
    myLL.add(1243242);
    System.out.println(myLL);

    myLL = deleteDups(myLL);
    System.out.println(myLL);
}

private static LinkedList<Integer> deleteDups(LinkedList<Integer> myLL) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    HashSet<Integer> myHashSet = new HashSet<Integer>();
    Iterator<Integer> itr;
    itr = myLL.iterator();

    while (itr.hasNext()) {
        if (!myHashSet.add(itr.next())) {
            itr.remove();
        }

    }

    return myLL;
}
```

}